# How to include a native DLL into my managed DLL/custom action for the WiX installer?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, pinvoke

I'm making a WiX/MSI installer that uses a custom action DLL written in C#. Inside that custom action I'm pinvoking a native/unmanaged DLL. Here's an example:

```
    [DllImport("log.dll",
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
        SetLastError = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern int CloseLog(IntPtr hLog);
```

The problem is that when my MSI runs and I invoke the custom action my call to `CloseLog` throws the `DllNotFoundException` exception.

I can manually add a link to `log.dll` into my custom action C# DLL project:

[image]

But the problem is that there's no way to specify which build of the `log.dll` to use from a C# project, i.e. x86/x64/debug/release.

So any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add any payload to the CA.dll by defining CustomActionContents in the project file like this (left path is in the CA right path is your local path).

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomActionContents>x64\log.dll=x64\log.dll;</CustomActionContents>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the DLL as content copylocal=true and it'll be included in the current directory of the custom action.

MSI is not platform agnostic so you should build a 32bit CA and 64bit CA to be consumed by a 32bit MSI and a 64bit MSI  if straight up x64/Release doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry, are you talking about adding the DLL as content copylocal to the WiX project, or to the custom action C# project?

Comment: The custom action project.  All the references and item content set to copy will get compressed inside the self extacting CA and be available in a temp directory at execution time.  That directory will be the working directory so LoadLibrary() should be able to find your DLL.

Comment: OK, but how would I include x86, or x64 version of the log.dll depending on the configuration setting in the Visual Studio?

Comment: That's more a build question then a wix question.  I suppose you could copy the correct file in before building the x86 configuration and then copy the correct file in again when building the x64 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have to answer my own question.

Evidently there's no way to do this via UI. So instead right-click your C# project in Solution Explorer, and select `Unload Project`, then locate the file name in the XML markup. So it turns out that instead of:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\..\x64\Debug\log.dll">
      <Link>Properties\log.dll</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

you can do:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\..\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\log.dll">
      <Link>Properties\log.dll</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then right-click the project again and select `Reload Project`.

It won't show correctly in the properties window, but it will compile according to selected configuration.